# Rails Nested create STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, single-table-inheritance, sti

I have 4 clases, with an STI on Instance.

Workspace, Project, Task, Instance, (type1 < Instance) and (type2 < Instance).

With proper associations. (Workspace has_many projects, has_many task through projects, so on)

And I have this nested create (worked before implementing STI):

```
if (%w(type1 type2).include?(params[:type]))

 sti_class = params[:type].classify.constantize

 workspaces.find_by_name(name: w_name). 
 projects.where( name: p_name).first_or_create!.
 tasks.where(name: t_name).first_or_create!.
 sti_class.create()
```

now, that doesn't work, I can't figure out a way.

However, the following works, but I want to keep the nested create.

```
task=  workspaces.find_by_name(name: w_name). 
        projects.where( name: p_name).first_or_create!.
        tasks.where(name: t_name).first_or_create!

sti_class.create(task_id: task.id)
```

How can I keep the nested create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I could immediately deduce is that the `sti_class` method isn't defined in your `Task` model, as you're adding it to the method chain.

Don't really think you're following the best practice here, but to immediately resolve the issue, you should probably do something like:

```
if (%w(type1 type2).include?(params[:type]))
 # depending on the association between the type(s) and the tasks, 
 # you'd need to either singularize or pluralize here, I'd assume 
 # task has many types, therefore pluralize

 sti_class = params[:type].pluralize

 # if you're already calling `find_by_name`, you don't need to pass 
 # the name option here anymore, but the name argument

 workspaces.find_by_name(w_name). 
 projects.where(name: p_name).first_or_create!.
 tasks.where(name: t_name).first_or_create!.
 send(sti_class).create
```